# Email cannot be null or empty while creating new user?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver3, asp.net-identity-3

I am using IdentityServer 3 for authentication. I am storing users in SQL DB using asp.net identity framework. IndentityServer team has provided simple [IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager.AspNetIdentity) library for administrators to manage users.

I followed the [video here](https://vimeo.com/125426951) and configured my application.

I have my own `ApplicationUser` and `ApplicationUserManager` class as below

```
public class ApplicationUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser
{
}

public class ApplicationUserManager : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore store, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
        : base(store)
    {
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true                
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        EmailService = new EmailService();
        SmsService = new SmsService();

        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("UserToken"));
        }
    }       
}
```

When i try to create user, i get error

> email cannot be null or empty.

[image]

I can get rid of this error by setting `RequireUniqueEmail` to `false` in `ApplicationUserManager`. However that is not my requirement. I want to keep `RequireUniqueEmail` to `true`

**Question**
How do i get Email address field to appear on create new user page. Note that `ApplicationUser` is derived from `IdentityUser` that already has Email property. So i am not sure why its not appearing on create new user page?

**Update 1**
So i looked at the code for [new user in github](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager/blob/master/source/Core/Assets/Templates/users/new.html), however its developed in angular. I'm not familiar with angular syntax :( and how the model is passed to view. I am not sure what do i need to do in consumer application to enable email field on new user screen.

Answer (score 2):

I partially solved my problem

The create user page shows only required property of `IndetityUser` ( in my case it `ApplicationUser` that is derived from `IdentityUser`). The `Email` property is in `IdentityUser` class but its virtual. So i can simply override the property in ApplicationUser and add required attribute

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public override string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This will add email field on Create User Page as i want. However when i edit user it shows email field twice. ( for me its okay for time being since this functionality is internal only)